# How to not select if value starts with str% but does not end with %str , regex example

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose I have

- Red.House.Value
- Red.House
- Green.House

in column1

I want to select everything, except if the value starts with "Red.House%" but ignore when it ends with .Value

Result should look like this:

- Red.House.Value
- Green.House

Regex:
https://regex101.com/r/vM0pQ3/1   ^(?=Red.House)(?!.*Value).*

I'm coming from excel, not sure what's the best practive in oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE column1 NOT LIKE 'Red.House%' OR column1 LIKE '%.Value'
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much of it, but there IS a regular expression function in oracle that you could use in your predicates:

WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (field_name, '^(?=Red.House)(?!.Value)');

More here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

Comment: i had problems with this solution somehow, i think the oracle regex syntax is slightly different or I'm missing something, anyway Santi gave a very good and easy solution. THx!

Comment: Yes I just pasted your expression in there... I didn't test.  I'm sure the format will vary, and as you pointed out, it is not necessary with the option of simply adding more predicates.